# How to remove port number from web service endpoint in wsdl file

Tags: java, web-services, https, apache-axis

I am working on migration of web service from `AXIS-1` to `AXIS-2`, every thing was going good till the it was on my local system, when deployed these services to SIT server I can see that the endpoint generated by `AXIS-2` in `WSDL` files is having the port number which is not supposed to be there, as in production environment the URL's of services is not having port number. The port number it is having is the same port number, which I configured in `axis2.xml`, and I did it as these service will be available on `https`.

I want to know is there any way to remove the port number from the endpoint in `WSDL` file or not.

I know that while calling the service we can override the end point, but the user of our services are using `WSDL` dynamically, so end point needs to be correct.

Please suggests.

Answer (score 1):

If the URLs of your web service on SIT do not have ports in them, it means they are using default ports as per the HTTP or HTTPS defaults i.e.

https://stackoverflow.com/ = http://stackoverflow.com:80/

or

https://stackoverflow.com/ = https://stackoverflow.com:443/

so you can specify the same in your axis2.xml

Also, there is a property called hostname in axis2.xml which should also be specified as the host name of your SIT server.

This should give you the correct endpoints in the WSDL generated.